# How do I append a string to a selected option in a drop down list without having it shown in the list itself?

Tags: html, select, append, dropdown

I have a drop down list as follows:

```
<select id='list'>
<option value='1'>1</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
<option value='3'>3</option>
</select>
```

However, on selection of one of these options, I need to see the option selected as "option selected / number of options". For example, if I select 1, I need the drop down to show "1/3" and not just "1". Essentially, I need the "/3" part to be appended to any option that is selected. Does anyone have any ideas for this? Because I seem to have run out of mine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must be looking like this, which can be done using simple jQuery.

**HTML:**

```
<select id='list'>
  <option value='1/3'>1</option>
  <option value='2/3'>2</option>
  <option value='3/3'>3</option>
</select>
<div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("select").change(function(){
var str = $("#list").val();
$("div").html(str);
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/shishirmax/rmg75xs3/

Comment: Well, it is almost what I am looking for. But instead of having it in a separate division, I need to be able to see "1/3" in the drop down itself where you see the option selected. But again, the list should contain just the number '1' and not '1/3'. I hope I am getting through to you. And I am actually hoping for a slight change. The values should be " 1 2 3", the text should be " 1 2 3". On selection, it should show "1/3". The values are "1/3 2/3 3/3" in the fiddle.